Cointegration when one variable is seasonal and another is not
I have two variables: one has a seasonal 12-month pattern and another is seasonally adjusted. I need to make a long-term forecast for 10 years. To do this, one can try out an Error Correction Model if the cointegration exists.
Whether these empirical strategies could work?

To use seasonal (as dependent variable) and non-seasonal (independent variable) in the cointegration equations? In this case, residuals could be white noise with seasonal pattern. So, they are not stationary?

To estimate a cointegration relationship with seasonal dummies (something like control variables). In this case my residuals exhibit fluctuations from the equilibrium level and can be stationary.


Most papers I found use either both seasonal series or seasonally adjusted in forecasting with ECM model. What of if I need to predict both trend and seasonal fluctuations of my dependent variable…
